# Is it possible to match a partial word in perl when using an if statement (bash example included)

Tags: perl, if-statement

What's is the correct way to match a partial word in perl? For example I want to match "CentOS" so results like CentOS 6, CentOS 7 and CentOS 8 are matched.

I know how to do this in bash, like this:

```
if [[ "$os" == *"CentOS"* ]]; then
   echo $centosversion
else
   echo $differentos
fi
```

With the above bash example it will find any result with "CentOS" inside.

How do I achieve this with the perl code below?

```
if ($os eq "CentOS") {
    print "$centosversion";
} else {
    print "$differentos";
}
```

I tried using:

```
($os eq *"CentOS"*)
```

and

```
(($os eq *"CentOS"*))
```

But that seems to be incorrect?

Maybe I am doing it completely wrong, but I don't know much about perl.
I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`index()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function - which looks for strings inside other strings.

```
if (index($os, 'CentOS') != -1) {
  print "$centosversion";
} else {
  print "$differentos";
}
```

Another alternative would be a regex match. But, for fixed strings, that would probably be overkill.

```
if ($os =~ /CentOS/) {
  print "$centosversion";
} else {
  print "$differentos";
}
```

Comment: I personally think that even though a regex for a fixed string is overkill, it's much easier to read, and therefore a better solution than `index`.

Comment: @Dada it's for me indeed "better" readable and understandable.

Comment: Unless performance is key, regex (`=~`) compared to `index` is (a) more readable and easy understand, as @Dada and @Joanne mentioned, (b) more commonly used, and (c) more maintainable and extensible, for example if the developer needs to find the version later: `my ($distro, $version) = $os =~ / ( centos | ubuntu | ... ) \s* (...version pattern...) }xmsi;`